# openpyxl(3.0.3) save function takes long

Tags: python, openpyxl

Please help me with openpyxl issues.
It's ok If you get better choice using another excel library.

I load existing excel file like this:

```
...
# load workbook
self._wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=self._file_name)
...
```

after load, I read data, process them and save data like this:

```
# integrate database content
# _database, _uniques are sheet.
for index in range(2, self._database.max_row):
    party = self._database.cell(row=index, column=DATABASE_PARTIES_COL_NUM)
    if party != '':
        unique_parties_list.update({party: party})
    party = self._database.cell(row=index, column=DATABASE_PARTIES_COL_NUM + 1)
    if party != '':
        unique_parties_list.update({party: party})

for index, unique_party in enumerate(unique_parties_list):
    self._uniques.cell(row=UNIQUES_FIRST_ROW + index,
                       column=NAMESPARTIES_UNIQUE_PARTIES_LIST_COL_NUM,
                       value=unique_party)

self._wb.save(self._file_name)
```

save function will be invoked serveral times.
As I invoke save function more and more, it's getting slowly more and more.

Comment: If saving takes a long time, then the obvious solution is to save *once*, when you are done with manipulating the data. Is their any particular reason why you are not doing that?

Comment: Also, you might want to look at [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) for data manipulation. There are several tutorials for excel and pandas. [Here](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/excel-and-pandas/) is one of them.

Comment: @RolandSmith, I need to read and write same excel file and it works with my current code. but saving speed is too slow.

Comment: I understand that it is slow.  That is why you should only do it only once.

Comment: @RolandSmith, is there any way to contact with you? I really need your help. I will show you my current code, you should look at my code and give me some advise. My email is webdevsmart@hotmail.com. My Skype is live:webdevsmart.